# How to block a site on Firefox on Mac?

Tags: firefox

I visit one social network site that loads another social network site in an iframe.

Is there a way to block a specific site on Firefox on Mac?

For example, pintrest.com has an updated cookie. I don't have an account there and don't visit the site.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One option if you (and no one else who uses your computer) ever intends to use that site, would be to create a **black hole host table entry**. What that does is forces your computer to resolve that DNS entry to an alternate IP address (like localhost/127.0.0.1). Since the IP address is not correct, attempts to access that site would fail and prevent your computer from loading any content.

Note: Make sure you use an IP address that doesn't have a different web server or you may accidentally load content from *that* site. Localhost is usually a safe bet unless you're running your own server.

https://www.imore.com/how-edit-your-macs-hosts-file-and-why-you-would-want

> Open a Finder window. Select Applications from the sidebar.
>
> Open Finder, then click on Applications Double-click on Utilities.
>   Double-click Terminal.
>
> Double-click on Utilities, then double-click on Terminal In the
>   Terminal window, you will need to enter a command to open the Nano
>   text editor. You will need your administrator password, as well.
>
> type sudo nano /etc/hosts and then hit return. Enter your
>   administrator password and then hit return.
>
> Enter enter Nano Text Editor in Terminal You're now in the Nano text
>   editor.
>
> Map the IP address in the Nano text editor If you want to add a new
>   device or domain, move the cursor using the arrow keys and position it
>   after the text in the window. Then, begin typing.
>
> If you're mapping a particular IP address on your local network to a
>   domain, you can type the IP address, hit tab, then type the domain
>   name.
>
> Conversely, if you'd like to make sure a web URL doesn't go to its
>   intended site — if you're trying to keep your Mac away from certain
>   sites, use "127.0.0.1." That'll map it back to your Mac. Even if your
>   Mac is assigned a different IP address by its router, 127.0.0.1
>   defaults to the local machine thanks to the default settings in that
>   hose file.
>
> Once you're done, hold down the control and O keys to save the file,
>   then control and X to exit.
>
> One last step Back at the command line, type sudo killall -HUP
>   mDNSResponder then type return. That will flush your Mac's DNS cache,
>   so it doesn't get confused by any changes you've made to the Hosts
>   file.

Answer (score 1):

I understand you are concerned with the case where going on one website
brings in cookies from other websites. These unintended cookies are called
"third-party cookies", since you are the first party and the website
you are displaying is the second.

See the Mozilla article
[Disable third-party cookies in Firefox to stop some types of tracking by advertisers](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/disable-third-party-cookies)
that explains how to block such cookies.

I prefer not to describe here the method of blocking the cookies,
since in case of a change of procedure in the future, my answer will not be updated,
but the Mozilla Support article will certainly be updated.

But since it's being demanded :

- Click the menu button and choose Options
- Select the Privacy & Security panel and go to the Cookies and Site Data section.
- In the drop-down menu next to Accept third-party cookies and site data choose Never.
- Close the about:preferences page. Any changes you've made will automatically be saved.

Comment: OK That makes sense. It was suggested the site was being loaded in an iframe. I've disabled third party cookies for now. I upvoted but will leave this open since now I would like to put a few social networks on a no load list.

Comment: If you are using Firefox, you might also have a look at the [NoScript add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/noscript/?), although it requires some knowledge.

Comment: Does NoScript block sites or block cookies?

Comment: It blocks JavaScript. For me it's a security measure.

Answer (score 1):

The question mentioned that a problem website was loading a 3rd party site in an iframe.  The extension AdBlock Plus can help with that.  You will have to train it using 'Block this element'

Answer (score 1):

If you are not only concerend about 3rd party cookies but any type of "3rd party" access you can use the addon [uMatrix](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/umatrix/). It's very flexible much more so than AdBlock but you have to sort of know what you are doing.

I had very specific ideas about what my browser should be allowed to access from other domains (like google analytic etc.). It was a little painstaking to configure what's allowed and what isn't, for (a simple) example for "superuser.com" google-analytics.com is off limits but ajax.googleapies.com is required.

[image]

But only to deny certain sites should be fairly easy: just block all access on those domains and allow everything else.